# Rails 3: Mongoid returns #<Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo:ID> tag with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, iteration

I've got an array of @contacts that is being iterated on a different model controller view:

```
<%= @contacts.each do |item| %>
<p>
<%= item.name %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Here's what the controller looks like:

```
@user = current_user
@contacts =  Contact.desc('created_at').where(:user_id => @user.id)
```

It functions as anticipated but drops this line with the iterated text:

```
#<Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo:0x007fe0bc0efbd8>
```

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @contacts.each do |item| %>
```

to

```
<% @contacts.each do |item| %>
```

(remove the =)

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Why does it do that?

Comment: Any ruby that appears inside of `<%= %>` will have its output appear in the html. But `<% %>` will have the ruby output suppressed, which is why it is only used for control structures, like 'if, for, do etc.'

Comment: Clear to me now. Thanks again!